# What is determing which `malloc` will be called for an injected code?

Tags: malloc, hook, code-injection, dynamic-linking, frida

I'm using frida to hook various functions of the Firefox web browser running atop of Windows. One of the symbols I hooked was `mozglue::malloc()` which calls for the `jemalloc` allocator.
In the process address-space there are three `malloc()` symbols:

1. In `msvcrt.lib` (static linking)
2. In `ucrtbase.dll` for dynamic linking
3. The already mentioned in `mozglue.dll`

I was expecting that all memory allocations that made by the Firefox processes will be allocated by the `mozglue::malloc()` and of course this truely happens.

I didn't expect that memory allocations that made by the frida JS agent which was injected to the target process will also be allocated using `jemalloc`, and honestly I still can't figure out why.

frida couldn't possibly know that there is a `mozglue::malloc()` symbol when its first attaching to a process, from the frida point of view there is a simple call for `malloc()`, so how and why this call is redirected from the default CRT symbols to the Mozila dll? This probably have something to do with the PE design, but I can't put the finger on it...

Thank for any help / insight / answer

Answer (score 1):

`mozglue::malloc` shouldn't even be the only function called inside Firefox, because some system functions called by Firefox will use system malloc.

I see only one explanation: Firefox replaces original malloc calls in memory with its own version of malloc. Having a check at the source code supports this idea: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/memory/build/replace_malloc.h